# Is there a way in Google SSO to force the user to re-enter their google password and not automatically sign in?

Tags: authentication, single-sign-on, google-signin, flags, google-sso

I need to give Google SSO a flag that force the user to reauthenticate when signing in and not to sign in automatically, I have read about the scopes/flags that could be sent with the request and didn't find relative answer, there is a flag called 'prompt' that could be set to 'consent' which ask the user to confirm they want to login but not to renter their Google password.
This option is exists in other sources that called **Force Authentication** but not with google.
Please confirm if there is option or not right now to make that and if not please let me know if this is something that you are working on. Thanks

I have tried searching for flags to force authentication when using Google SSO to let the user re enter their Google password

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The OIDC specification has a value `login` for the `prompt` parameter. If you send `prompt=login` with your authorization request, then the user will be re-authenticated. However, even though Google claims to use OIDC, they seem not to support that value for the prompt parameter. The values that they support don't actually have the function you need, so I don't think it's currently possible to force that on Google auth.